# How can i fetch data and use it in viewdidload ...not inside function?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to print fetched data from `viewDidLoad`.
I don't want to print it from the custom function itself.
when I call the fetch function in `viewDidLoad`.It should fetch all datas.
and after that I should be able to access or print that data from `viewDidLoad` itself or wherever may be.

```
class ContactViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var lblEmail: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblLocation: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var mapUIView: UIView!

var email = String()
var location = String()
var lati = Double()
var long = Double()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.fetchData()
    print(email)
    self.lblEmail.text = self.email


}

func fetchData(){

    let manager = APIManager()
    manager.parsingGet(url: BaseURL.contact) { (JSON, Status) in

        if Status {
            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
            let data = dict!["data"] as! [String:Any]

           // let lat = data["latitude"] as! Double
           // let lon = data["longitude"] as! Double
            let mail = data["email"] as! String
            let loc = data["location"] as! String

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.email = mail
                self.location = loc
               // self.lati = lat
               //self.long = lon

            }


        }


    }


}


}
```

Comment: Related: [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function?r=SearchResults&s=1|67.5381)

Comment: Why do you insist on getting all the data before `viewDidLoad` returns? Getting data from the Internet takes _time_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot print any data that you will be getting from an API response in `viewDidLoad()` method as all the lines of code specified in the `viewDidLoad()` method will be executed back to back and will not wait for your API call to be finished.

Even if you have a fast server it will take a couple of milliseconds to hit your API and get a response. Your compiler would have executed all lines of code with the `viewDidLoad()` method by then.

So you might as well print the data in `DispatchQueue.main.async` in your `fetchData()` method.

You can try using callback functions. That could be a possible way of achieving what you want. Try something like this ....

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    getData(completion:{ result in
    print(email)
    self.lblEmail.text = self.email
})


}

func getData(completion: (Bool)->()) {
    if status{
        let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
        let data = dict!["data"] as! [String:Any]
        let mail = data["email"] as! String
        let loc = data["location"] as! String

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.email = mail
            self.location = loc
            completion(true)

        }

    } else {
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`parsingGet` work asynchronously. The solution is pretty easy: Assign the value to the label in the completion handler of the API

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.fetchData()
}

func fetchData() {

    let manager = APIManager()
    manager.parsingGet(url: BaseURL.contact) { (JSON, status) in

        if status {
            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
            let data = dict!["data"] as! [String:Any]

            // let lat = data["latitude"] as! Double
            // let lon = data["longitude"] as! Double
            let mail = data["email"] as! String
            let loc = data["location"] as! String

            self.email = mail
            self.location = loc
            print(mail)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {    
                self.lblEmail.text = mail
            }
        }
    }
}
```